# Identifying an Sharepoint component on a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I have a web part on a sharepoint site that is placed by somebody else. And I can not find what web part this is.

[image]

Does anybody know what web part this is? And how can I determine what web part this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append `?contents=1` to the page URL. That will take you to the Web Part Maintenance page where you can see all the web parts on the page and their types.

[image: Web Part Maintenance page]